# Асинхронный http сервер на питоне

Tags: python, tornado

Подскажите как реализоват, целую неделю уже воюю. Нужен http сервер который принимает и обрабатывает запросы асинхронно. Допустим тебе приходит одновременно 5 запросов, и вместо того что бы ставить эти пять запросов в очередь он их выполняет одновременно. Пробовал торнадо пробовал [базовый http](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1089737/%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-http-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-python)
но так и непонял как сделать асинхронную обрботку

Comment: Как я вам уже писал - просто возьмите aiotttp, например

Comment: не понятно что именно надо распаралелить. что в ответе.

Comment: Ни в коем случае не хочу обидеть, но сомневаюсь, что кто-нибудь здесь сможет сделать волшебные пасы руками для увеличения вашей понятливости. Читайте что вообще такое асинхронность, читайте документацию по asyncio, читайте документацию к асинхронным web-фреймворкам, разберитесь с примерами из документации, поищите примеры на github'е. Потом приходите с конкретными проблемами, если они у вас возникнут.